# regex to split number from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers

How to split and select which is number using regex. User can enter string like:

1dozen
3 dozen
dozen1    <= unlikely but assume user will type that too

30/kg

I still find out with the incomplete one:

```
/[a-z](?=\d)|\d(?=[a-z])/i
```

But missing space and forward slash. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the user only enters number plus text then parseInt(str,10) will do the job

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lookarounds are completely unnecessary here!

See http://jsfiddle.net/5WJ9v/

The code:

```
var text = "1dozen 3 dozen dozen1 30/kg";
var regex = /(\d+\.|\d+)+/g;
alert(text.match(regex));
```

You get a match object with all of your numbers.

The script above correctly alerts `1,3,1,30`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '1dozen 3 dozen dozen1 30/kg';
str.match(/\d+/g); // ["1", "3", "1", "30"]
```