# Update all numbers in string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

**Main question is how I can update all numbers in string?**

Examples where I want to update numbers in string:

- `-ms-transform: rotate(7deg);`
- `margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;`
- `Value10isMoreThan5`

So every "chunk" of numbers should be handled separately (e.g. `10` or `1 0` or `1px2`, no matter if it's space or character between segment of numbers).

I got this working when I use spaces to split string, but it doesn't work in cases when string has no spaces `rotate(7deg)`. Here is some small piece of "spaghetti code" example.

```
// Basic lerp
function lerp (min, max, amount) {
    return min + amount * (max - min);
}

// Lerp values in string
function lerpAllNumbers (a, b, amount) {
    var aNumbers = separateNumbers(a);
    var bNumbers = separateNumbers(b);
    var returnValue = null;
    if (aNumbers.length === bNumbers.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < aNumbers.length; i++) {
            var searchString = aNumbers[i].value + aNumbers[i].extension;
            var newValue = lerp(aNumbers[i].value, bNumbers[i].value, amount).toFixed(3) + aNumbers[i].extension;
            returnValue = a.toString().replace(searchString, newValue);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

// Separate numbers from string and create object with value and extension
function separateNumbers(text) {
    var splitter = text.toString().split(" ");
    var returnArray = [];
    splitter.forEach(function(item){
        var numberObj = {
            value: parseFloat(item),
            extension: item.replace(/^-?\d+((.|,)\d+)?/g, '')
        }
        returnArray.push(numberObj);
    });
    return returnArray;
}
```

Sorry if there is duplicates. I've found already useful post like this one: [regex to split number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857513/regex-to-split-number-from-string)

But none for this case where I need to update multiple numbers and put them back to string in right places after update.

**Is there smarter/easier way to update all numbers in strings with JavaScript (Vanilla or jQuery)?**

Comment: I think you'll want to use `.replace()` with a regex pattern and a custom replacement function. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with an anonymous callback method:

```js
// Basic lerp
function lerp (min, max, amount) {
    return Number(min + amount * (max - min));
}

var s = "-ms-transform: rotate(7deg);";
var max = 15, amount = 2;
console.log(
  s.replace(/-?\d*[,.]?\d+/g, function(m) {
    return lerp(Number(m), max, amount).toFixed(3);
  })
);
```

The pattern is `/-?\d*[,.]?\d+/g` that matches multiple occurrences of an optional minus sign, 0+ digits followed with a `,` or `.` and then 1+ digits.

The `function(m){}` is the anonymous callback method passed to the `String#replace` method as a replacement argument where the value can be passed to other methods.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor for pointing right direction. I guess I've finally found solution based on your answer. I'm not sure if it's proper way to do that, but it works now. Created new answer because too messy code to comment here. Please correct me if it's wrong. Thanks to you again.

Comment: Sure! Accepted sir!

Answer (score 1):

This answer based on @Wiktor Stribiżew answer and it replaces all values from string using other string values and calculate lerp values from those.

```
// Basic lerp function
function lerp (min, max, amount) {
    return min + amount * (max - min);
}

function lerpAllNumbers (a, b, amount) {

    a = 'rotate(-35.4deg 45.3deg)';
    b = 'rotate(100deg 200deg)';
    bArr = b.match(/-?\d*[,.]?\d+/g);

    console.log(
        a.replace(/-?\d*[,.]?\d+/g, function(m) {
            return utils.lerp(Number(m), bArr.shift(), amount).toFixed(3)
        })
    ); // rotate(99.946deg 199.938deg)
}
```